# CKEditor issue with Bootstrap v4 modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

The issue and the bugfix when using CKEditor inside Bootstrap v3 modal is described [here >>](https://gist.github.com/Reinmar/b9df3f30a05786511a42#ckeditor-inside-bootstrap-modals)

With Bootstrap v4 the function name changed from **enforceFocus** to **_enforceFocus**

Unfortunately my js skills are insufficient to translate the suggested bugfix for Bootstrap v3 to Bootstrap v4.

Any help is appriciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function _enforceFocus() {
    var _this4 = this;
    $(document).off(Event.FOCUSIN).on(Event.FOCUSIN, function (event) {
        if (
            document !== event.target
            && _this4._element !== event.target
            && $(_this4._element).has(event.target).length === 0
            && !$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select')
            && !$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')
        ) {
            _this4._element.focus();
        }
    });
};
```

I took the original function **_enforceFocus** from Bootstrap v4 and added `!$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select')` and `!$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')` to the if statement.

Comment: Tip: I removed this part "off(Event.FOCUSIN)" because it was unabling click of some buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to pass the option `{focus: false}` when displaying the modal. This option is new in Bootstrap 4 (see [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#options)). Using this option will prevent Bootstrap from calling **_enforceFocus**.